# how to get virtual user number, iteration number and total virtual users count during runtime in Gatling Scala script?

Tags: scala, gatling

Is there any way to get virtual user number, iteration number and total virtual users count during runtime in Gatling Scala script and how can use those information in script like in requests or custom code?

I am looking for similar functions like ${__threadNum} and ${__iterationNum} of JMeter.

**For example-**
If I have one scenario and I am running it with 10 virtual users and each virtual user will iterate the scenario 20 times then how will how know the iteration/repeat number with respect to each virtual user. And also how will I know the current status of virtual user (means which virtual user is running now and how many iteration it has completed) and save it in variable so that I can use it in script.

Answer (score 0):

First, Gatling's **virtual users are not [threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)**.
You probably use this term because of JMeter's leaking implementation detail.

In Gatling, you get real time stats in the console.

If you want real time charts, the best solution is [FrontLine](https://gatling.io/gatling-frontline/).

Comment: Thanks, is there any function/alternative to get virtual user number, total virtual user count and iteration number so that I can use in the script itself? Like we use ${__threadNum} and ${__iterationNum} in JMeter.

Comment: If you're using loops, you have access to the loop index, if that's what you mean. see https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/scenario/#loop-statements

Comment: If I have one scenario and I am running it with 10 virtual users and each virtual user will iterate the scenario 20 times then how will how know the iteration/repeat number with respect to each virtual user. And also how will I know the current status of virtual user (means which virtual user is running now and how many iteration it has completed) and save it in variable so that I can use it in script.

Comment: I am looking for similar to ${__threadNum} and ${__iterationNum} of JMeter functions in Gatling.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to get the number of times a request with a specific name has been sent. I want to make 50% of requests be async, but because sync takes so much longer, a 50% chance of being  async ends up being like 10% sync 90% async. I  could account for this if I had a way of accessing # of matching requests of each type.